# Download html canvas image and pdf in Phonegap

Tags: canvas, download, phonegap

I have a webpage in html/css/js where I create and populate an html canvas (update wheel), and a function to save it as a .png file (download as image) that works perfectly in the browser (IE excluded).
http://seraustralasia.com/wheel/wheel.html

I've turned it into a WebApp using Phonegap. Everything works fine except for the download. 
I also have a .pdf file on the homepage http://seraustralasia.com/wheel/index.html
that works on the browser but can't be downloaded when tested on android.

I've tried cordova-plugin-file-transfer but it doesn't work. It seems there should be an easy fix to allow the file to be downloaded to the phone, but in hours of search I could not find a solution...

Any suggestion?

Thanks